# Django AutoComplete display related foreign details in dropdown

Tags: django, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I'm new to autocomplete in Django 2.0.

I have it working however I cant seem to make the django admin change the label_from_instance when using the AutoComplete feature.

Does anybody know how to modify the autocomplete_fields lables?

Normally without autocomplete my djangoadmin get form would look like the below

```
   def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ChampProductMappingAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['sharepoint_product'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{} {}".format(obj.product_name,  obj.final_publications_product_id)
```

if i use

```
 autocomplete_fields = ['sharepoint_product']
```

it just uses the standard object (ID) label

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve the same thing, but on investigating, I can't see a way to do it easily.

The results are loaded via AJAX as opposed to rendered with the page since its an autocomplete.
When you look at the Django source for the AJAX view (https://github.com/django/django/blob/43f54e136e9282f5c0bfcf1169d0d59b3c365add/django/contrib/admin/views/autocomplete.py#L31) you can see that the label is set to `str(obj)` and there is no easy way to change that behaviour.